# Move snappy.parquet file into impala or beeline as a table

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, impala, beeline

I have a snappy.parquet file which I would like to move in its entirety into a table through either impala or beeline, creating a table by

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS first_test LIKE PARQUET '/user/my_user/my_table/part-00000-c0544fc8-b709-4408-8e90-f0f9e4050691-c000.snappy.parquet'
```

does not work for some reason as it says `Fetched 0 row(s) in 0.31s.`
When I read this file in spark through spark.read.parquet, it returns the table that I'm looking for (over 1000 rows).

I cannot directly write to Hive as I do not have the permissions to myDF.write.saveAsTable.

Is there a way to make a table through impala or beeline even though impala and beeline only have read and execute permissions in hdfs and not write. Or would I have to give impala and beeline the permission to write in hdfs as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is essentially create the table based on the parquet metadata contained in the file. If you want to read the data as well, you can specify the table location as follow

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
first_test 
LIKE PARQUET '/user/my_user/my_table/part-00000-c0544fc8-b709-4408-8e90-f0f9e4050691-c000.snappy.parquet'
location 
'/user/my_user/my_table/'
```

It will automatically read all the files inside of the specified folder location

Comment: I've tried that, however as I've mentioned, I don't have write permissions from hdfs so beeline cannot move it into the hive warehouse.

Comment: it does not need  to move it .. it will point the table to your location.

Comment: I did need to provide permission to beeline to access hdfs, just fyi.